# SWIFT 2.3 - take out html tags from string taken from JSON url

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I It shows the raw HTML of the post.

I would like to know how to convert the HTML into plain text for just the UITextView.

Thanks! swift 2.3 ?? if any one could help i'll be pleased 
`enter code here`

```
class TransportationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textArea: UITextView!

    var tableData = []



            self.tableData = myResult

            self.titleLabel.text = self.tableData[4].valueForKey("Title") as? String
            self.textArea.text = self.tableData[4].valueForKey("Details") as? String

            ASProgressHud.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)


        }) { (error, errorMessage) in

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Connection error, please try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the exact output you're trying to work with, but here's an extension I use to strip HTML from a string.  This is in Swift 3

```
extension String {

    func convertFromHTML() -> String? {

        //convert any html escaping
        if let htmldata = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmldata, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil) {
            //remove any non ascii characters
            return attributedString.string
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```